# Struggling to amend the code to scroll to div id

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have a div id of "selship" defined:

```
<div style="position:relative;" id="selship">
```

If I click "...checkout.html/#selship" it will go to correct position.

However, I have tried this in the Jquery code but it is not adding #selship to the URL

```
<button class="<?php echo $buttonclass ?>" type="reset" onClick="window.location.href='<?php echo JRoute::_('index.php?option=com_virtuemart&view=cart'); ?>/#selship" ><?php echo JText::_('COM_VIRTUEMART_CANCEL'); ?></button>
```

Can anyone tell me how to make this work.

Thanks

Comment: Where is the jQuery code? View the page source, look what is generated. You missed quotes, viewing the source, you would see that.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that you forgot a closing `'` after the URL. It should be like this:

`window.location.href='<?php echo JRoute::_('index.php?option=com_virtuemart&view=cart'); ?>/#selship'"` in the `onClick` handler. Also, just so you know, if you just want to add `#selship` to the end of the URL, you can simply do `window.location.hash='#selship';` instead

Comment: Thanks for this, I have tried both these options without luck. Firebug shows that clicking on the save button should put in the #selship at the end of the URL but it is not doing it. It must be something to do with jquery.

Comment: I have figured out that it is nothing to do with this part of the code. It is this part of the code that is important <button class="default" type="submit">Save</button>. This calls COM_VIRTUEMART_SAVE which is where I think I need to look.